# PHP Convert string to xml then to an array

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I get the following from a web service as a response, it is XML but returned as a string (although formatted just like xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PickResponse>
    <Files>
        <File file="CLIENTS">
            <Item item="1">
                <AuditInd>
                    <AuditDetail>
                        <AuditStaffCd>XXX</AuditStaffCd>
                        <AuditEntryDt>XXX</AuditEntryDt>
                        <AuditTime>XXX</AuditTime>
                        <AuditCd>XXX</AuditCd>
                        <AuditHistoryRecordNumber>XXX</AuditHistoryRecordNumber>
                        <AuditProgram>XXX</AuditProgram>
                    </AuditDetail>
                </AuditInd>
                <ClientCd>XXX</ClientCd>
                <ClientName>XXX</ClientName>
                <BillToCode>XXX</BillToCode>
                <Addr1>XXX</Addr1>
                <PostCd>
                    <PostalCode>XXX</PostalCode>
                </PostCd>
                <City>XXX</City>
                <StateProvCd>XXX</StateProvCd>
                <Phone1Number>XXX</Phone1Number>
                <ReferenceCd>XXX</ReferenceCd>
                <ProducerCd>
                    <Producer1Cd>XXX</Producer1Cd>
                </ProducerCd>
                <ServicerCd>
                    <Servicer1Cd>XXX</Servicer1Cd>
                </ServicerCd>
                <CreditTerms>XXX</CreditTerms>
                <SourceCd>XXX</SourceCd>
                <SourceDt>XXX</SourceDt>
                <CatCd>
                    <Cat1Cd>XXX</Cat1Cd>
                </CatCd>
                <SICCd>XXX</SICCd>
                <RemarkText>XXX</RemarkText>
                <AccountingPhoneExtensionNumber>XXX</AccountingPhoneExtensionNumber>
            </Item>
        </File>
    </Files>
</PickResponse>
```

I need a way to convert strings into XML.  Any ideas?  I can't seem to find a string to xml script.

Answer:

I used the XMLtoArray() function, the source can be found on SO.

I had to strip off the xml tag within the string and replace the html characters for < and > and then print out the response from the soap request.

```
$response = str_replace('&lt;', '<', $response);
$response = str_replace('&gt;', '>', $response);
$response = str_replace('<?xml version="1.0"?>', '', $response);
$xmlnew = $this->XMLtoArray($response);
print_r($xmlnew);
```

This gave me a nice array!

Comment: Why not trying to use php soap library or other libraries for soap?

Comment: I tried using the soap library and I couldn't get this far to begin with.  I would get a NULL exception or would still get a string(0) "" response.  This way I am able to output the request (found another SO question to help) so I know what is going on.  The soap__getLastRequest etc was returning NULL previously.

Comment: I may have figured out the answer, I think this web service is case-sensitive.  I will post my findings shortly.

Comment: I got the response I need from the webservice, unfortunately it only allows for a string to be returned.  I need to dump my data into an array so I can use it.  So it seems I need to convert this string -> xml -> array.

Comment: If you're working with soap correctly you should never be interacting with raw xml.

Comment: I am working with raw xml because this was the only way I could monitor the status of the output / errors I was receiving previously.  Working manually with xml has enabled me to track where and what was going wrong with my ws call.

Comment: @MikeB - Also, the wsdl file indicates the method takes xml as well.

Comment: "enabled me to track where and what was going wrong with my ws call" - That's called debugging. Enabling tracing is like enabling debugging.. which you've now set to always on in a production setting. It's analogous to calling var_dump() on a variable, capturing the output, and running logic on it. Would you do that on production or only while you're developing?

Comment: This is not production, but an environment for me to learn.  I will now convert back to original soap calls now that I know the xml I am passing is correct.  Call it what you will, it gave me information I needed to understand the concept.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Answer:

I used the XMLtoArray() function seen below:

```
function XMLtoArray($XML)
{
    $xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
    xml_parse_into_struct($xml_parser, $XML, $vals);
    xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
    // wyznaczamy tablice z powtarzajacymi sie tagami na tym samym poziomie
    $_tmp='';
    foreach ($vals as $xml_elem) {
        $x_tag=$xml_elem['tag'];
        $x_level=$xml_elem['level'];
        $x_type=$xml_elem['type'];
        if ($x_level!=1 && $x_type == 'close') {
            if (isset($multi_key[$x_tag][$x_level]))
                $multi_key[$x_tag][$x_level]=1;
            else
                $multi_key[$x_tag][$x_level]=0;
        }
        if ($x_level!=1 && $x_type == 'complete') {
            if ($_tmp==$x_tag)
                $multi_key[$x_tag][$x_level]=1;
            $_tmp=$x_tag;
        }
    }
    // jedziemy po tablicy
    foreach ($vals as $xml_elem) {
        $x_tag=$xml_elem['tag'];
        $x_level=$xml_elem['level'];
        $x_type=$xml_elem['type'];
        if ($x_type == 'open')
            $level[$x_level] = $x_tag;
        $start_level = 1;
        $php_stmt = '$xml_array';
        if ($x_type=='close' && $x_level!=1)
            $multi_key[$x_tag][$x_level]++;
        while ($start_level < $x_level) {
            $php_stmt .= '[$level['.$start_level.']]';
            if (isset($multi_key[$level[$start_level]][$start_level]) && $multi_key[$level[$start_level]][$start_level])
                $php_stmt .= '['.($multi_key[$level[$start_level]][$start_level]-1).']';
            $start_level++;
        }
        $add='';
        if (isset($multi_key[$x_tag][$x_level]) && $multi_key[$x_tag][$x_level] && ($x_type=='open' || $x_type=='complete')) {
            if (!isset($multi_key2[$x_tag][$x_level]))
                $multi_key2[$x_tag][$x_level]=0;
            else
                $multi_key2[$x_tag][$x_level]++;
            $add='['.$multi_key2[$x_tag][$x_level].']';
        }
        if (isset($xml_elem['value']) && trim($xml_elem['value'])!='' && !array_key_exists('attributes', $xml_elem)) {
            if ($x_type == 'open')
                $php_stmt_main=$php_stmt.'[$x_type]'.$add.'[\'content\'] = $xml_elem[\'value\'];';
            else
                $php_stmt_main=$php_stmt.'[$x_tag]'.$add.' = $xml_elem[\'value\'];';
            eval($php_stmt_main);
        }
        if (array_key_exists('attributes', $xml_elem)) {
            if (isset($xml_elem['value'])) {
                $php_stmt_main=$php_stmt.'[$x_tag]'.$add.'[\'content\'] = $xml_elem[\'value\'];';
                eval($php_stmt_main);
            }
            foreach ($xml_elem['attributes'] as $key=>$value) {
                $php_stmt_att=$php_stmt.'[$x_tag]'.$add.'[$key] = $value;';
                eval($php_stmt_att);
            }
        }
    }
    return $xml_array;
}
```

Due to the nature of my string, I had to strip off the xml tag within the string and replace the html characters for < and > and then print out the response from the soap request.

```
$response = str_replace('&lt;', '<', $response);
$response = str_replace('&gt;', '>', $response);
$response = str_replace('<?xml version="1.0"?>', '', $response);
$xmlnew = $this->XMLtoArray($response);
print_r($xmlnew);
```

This gave me a nice array!

Comment: @putvande - I pasted the contents of the function into my post (taking no credit for the function).  I would appreciate if you could remove the -1

Comment: Sorry but this is just not an answer to your own question. You ask for a string to XML. This is XML to Array.

Comment: This is not true, as stated above the response from the web service is of type STRING, even thought it looks like xml.  I couldnt cast xml over the string and so I stripped out characters causing the problem (html characters).  Then I used the XML to Array function, which was my end game.